# Change the color of the hamburgericon in .netMaui

Tags: shell, xamarin, maui, .net-maui.shell

I have a .netMaui app with a flyoutmenu. The flyouticon or the hamburgericon has a white color. Now I want to change the color when the application is in whitemode. The problem: it doesn't change. I used the Shell.FlyoutIcon property.
[image]
[image]

First I tried AppThemeBinding but it didn't work. Then I used a diffrent icon with a black color to see if it changes. The icon changed and I had another shape but the color automaticly changed to white.

So what am I supposed to do to get a diffrent color?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you having this problem on Android or iOS? And may I know your .net maui version?

Comment: @HongxinSui-MSFT The problem is on Android. I don't know my current .netMaui version. Where can I find it, but I have the current VS version.

Comment: Ok, I know. You can try to use custom shell renderer in Maui.

Comment: @HongxinSui-MSFT And how do I use it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74253764/4308455 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits: ewerspej

You have to change the Shell.ForegroundColor and can make a AppThemeBinding.

Ref: [How to get the default shell flyout icon to react when android dark theme is switched on/off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74252720/how-to-get-the-default-shell-flyout-icon-to-react-when-android-dark-theme-is-swi/74253764#74253764)

Comment: is it possible to change the icon to a different image?